# Terraform plan failing while AWS Elasticache Redis cluster is scaling out

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, terraform, amazon-elasticache

Have made a redis cluster (cluster mode enabled) in AWS using Terraform; whenever the cluster is scaling, all terraform plan and apply actions fail.

This is a problem as while the Redis Cluster is auto-scaling, there is no ability to change any other resources in the AWS account from terraform. Given it takes 10~ minutes or so to scale out, this could become a general issue for maintenance of other components of the environment.

I have no need for terraform to manage the state of the cluster instances, only require it to initially bootstrap the cluster. Management and scaling of the cluster will be managed by a Lambda resource.

I expect that I should be able to perform terraform plan and apply operations in terraform on other AWS resources while the cluster is resizing.

### What I'm observing

When scaling-out Redis cluster in the AWS UI (either Adding shards, or nodes to a shard), existing nodes statuses change to "modifying", during which time, any terraform plan or apply operations fail:

```
Error: error listing tags for resource (arn:aws:elasticache:ap-southeast-2::cluster:router-redis-cache-0001-001): CacheClusterNotFound: router-redis-cache-0001-001 is either not present or not available.
        status code: 404, request id: b6cfcff3-dfa7-41cf-b099-0eb0c9767990
```

### Steps to reproduce

- Add the following to main.tf, :

```
# Configure your AWS Provider
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}

resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "this" {
  count = 1

  at_rest_encryption_enabled    = true
  multi_az_enabled              = true
  automatic_failover_enabled    = true
  replication_group_id          = "users-cache"
  replication_group_description = "Users Redis cache"
  node_type                     = "cache.t3.medium"
  parameter_group_name          = "default.redis6.x.cluster.on"
  port                          = 6379

  cluster_mode {
    num_node_groups         = 1 # Number of initial shards
    replicas_per_node_group = 1 # Number of initial replicas within each shard
  }

  apply_immediately = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Scaling the instances in AWS will change cluster_mode.num_node_groups, custer_mode.replicas_per_node_group;
      # disregard drift from initial configuration.
      cluster_mode,
    ]
  }
}
```

- terraform apply
- wait for operation to complete
- log into AWS account
- find Elasticache cluster
- scale out the cluster (e.g. click "Add shard")
- note that the cluster goes into 'modifying' state
- run `terraform plan`
- observe failure

Comment: If your cluster is in `modifying` state, usually you won't be able to do anything with it  till it finishes. This is common for many other aws resources.

Comment: @Marcin I'm not attempting to change the cluster itself while the cluster is scaling up/down; it's more that I can't modify [or even plan] changes to other [non-redis] resources while the cluster is scaling